pycharm Unresolved attribute reference 'astype' for class 'ndarray'

Q: How can I fix the bug where Pychram warns about numpy.ndarray attributes?
The code runs with no problem, however PyCharm keeps giving this warning:
Unresolved attribute reference 'astype' for class 'ndarray'

It's not only this, but other methods such as .tolist(), and np.sum().
I am using Python 3.9.7
PyCharm has been behaving very weirdly when it comes to numpy related code. any clues?

I was seeing this problem today, and it wasn't fixed by restarting or invalidating Pycharm's caches. It did go away after updating Pycharm to the latest version (2024.1.5) however.
